# ¿Cómo esperar a que se cargue un diálogo en Vue/Vuetify?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, vuetify

Mi código activa una ventana de diálogo por medio de EventBus, pero al hacerlo da error de *$refs of undefined*. Eso significa que aún no se carga por completo cuando manda llamar a $refs.

He intentado con **$nextTick** y no funciona, con **setTimeout** si funciona pero no creo que sea una buena práctica hacerlo.

```
export default {
    data: () => ({ dialog: false }),
    methods: {
        openDialog() {
            this.dialog = true
            this.$refs.input.focus()
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        EventBus.$on('open-dialog', this.openDialog)
    }
}
```

Comment: por que usas Event Bus?

Comment: Porque es un componente "nieto", hijo del hijo.

No supe cómo comunicarlos mas que con EventBus.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando dices una ventana de dialogo entiendo que te refieres una ventana de dialogo por javascript ¿no? ¿Porqué necesitas una ventana de navegador aparte? Lo cierto es que veo bastante más horrible usar ventanas de dialogo que eventos por EventBus. Quizás el objeto que devuelve el método para abrir diálogos en javascript tenga eventos que te indiquen si ya ha sido cargado, nunca lo he hecho la verdad.

¿Te has planteado hacer popups por HTML? Yo hice mi propia "librería" para popups. Le añadir controles para cambiar el tamaño de la ventana e incluso le hice un pequeño gestor para controlar el orden de apertura de forma que establece cuál va delante de cuál, una cosa muy sencilla pero muy útil. Además puedes cargar el componente de vue.js que quieras dentro de ellas, así decido lo que va en su interior. Lo que no he hecho es que puedas moverlas. No la tengo publicada porque no creía que mereciera la pena, me pareció muy sencillo. Si te decides por algo así quizás pueda ayudarte.